# How do you create an average time difference between records in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I desire to create an average time difference between device connections.

I have this query now thanks to ajreal. What I need to do now is create and average time between each device record being posted.

```
select device, count(*) as cnt, max(time)
from database.table
group by device
having cnt>1
order by device;
```

I have been playing around with TIMEDIFF but I need the average between all device records not just the min and max.

The table is structured like:

```
ID, device(string),
data1(int),data2(int), 
time(timestamp), 
data3(int),
data4(int)
```

How might I achieve my goal?

This is the table definition.

Field         Type          Null  Key  Default  Extra

id            int(11)       NO    PRI  NULL     auto_increment 
 device        varchar(15)   NO    MUL  NULL
 data1         decimal(5,2)  YES        NULL
 data2         decimal(5,2)  YES        NULL
 time          timestamp     YES        NULL
 data3         decimal(3,0)  YES        NULL
 data4         decimal(3,0)  YES        NULL

Thanks for looking at my problem @Chris Henry!

Comment: how is the difference calculated? is it like timestamp 2-timestamp 1,timestamp 3-timestamp 2,etc

Comment: What I’m looking for is first the time difference between each device (ts1 – ts2, ts2- ts3, ts3-ts4) then the average of that difference for each device. Thanks

Comment: I don't think this can be done in a sensible way with MySQL due to its lack of windowing functions. You'll probably get quicker what you want by doing that in your application

Comment: exactly, mySql could do that with scanning but it takes an awful long time and plus it's bad practice. This is a business side functionality IMO

Comment: Could you post your table definition?

Answer (score 2):

You have to convert your timestamp to a number in order to be able to round it. And when you have the average timestamp, convert it back to a date.

```
select device, count(*) as cnt, FROM_UNIXTIME(AVG(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time)), '%i:%s')
from database.table
group by device
having cnt>1
order by device;
```

---

Note: If you consider negative times, your average is obvious! If you don't then it is a better idea to calculate it with a scripting language (php, c#, ruby...)

```
average := avg(ts1–ts2, ts2-ts3, ts3-ts4)
= (ts1–ts2 + ts2-ts3 + ts3-ts4)/3
= (ts4-ts1)/3
```

Generalisation:

```
average = (last entry - first entry) / (number of entries - 1)
```

Comment: This is close, what this returns is the average date and time of the device records in the format yy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss. What I’m looking for is the average time deference  (mm:ss) between consecutive pair of records.

@pinouchon your correct. Your note shows the correct way.

Comment: Added a formating parameter to `FROM_UNIXTIME`. Example of formatting: '%Y %D %M %h:%i:%s %x' gives `2007 22nd July 07:46:11 2007`

Answer (score 1):

This will get you the time differences for every event (safely disregarding the
first one):

```
SELECT 
  device, 
  TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(time1, time0)) as diff
FROM 
  table t0
JOIN table t1 
  ON t0.device = t1.device
  AND t0.time < t1.time
LEFT JOIN table t2
  ON t1.device = t2.device
    AND t2.time < t1.time
    AND t2.time > t1.time
WHERE
  t2.id IS NULL
```

Then take the average of those by device.

```
SELECT device, AVG(diff)
FROM (
   put the above query here
) AS tbl
GROUP BY device
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT device
     , COUNT(*)   AS cnt
     , TIME_FORMAT( TIMEDIFF(MAX(`time`), MIN(`time`))  / (COUNT(*)-1) 
                  , '%H:%i:%s:%f' ) 
       AS avgTimeDiff
FROM database.table
WHERE `time` IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY device
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY device
```

Comment: I just tested you query and it seams to only calculate the avg for 3 out of 26 devices. The rest is NULL for the result. Is it in the , '%H:%m:%s:%f' formatting I tried variations of this but it does not fix the issue?

Comment: @pointhigh: Can you try this version? Perhaps the `time` field has `NULL` values for the rest of the devices?

Answer (score -2):

use AVG() http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg

Comment: AVG() gives me a number not sure what this number is?  If it is an average of the timestamps can I use time_to_sec?  I need to convert this to minutes seconds format.