# MySQL adding the difference between time values to find the avg difference.

Tags: mysql

I have a column that is Time formatted it needs to be sorted newest to oldest. What I would like to do is find the differences in time between each adjoin record. The tricky part is I need to sum all of the time differences then divide by the count – 1 of all the time records. Can this be done in MySQL

Comment: Didn't you get answers in your same question?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312055/how-do-you-create-an-average-time-difference-between-records-in-mysql

Comment: Not quite the answers were good but not exactly what I need. What those answers offered was an average time of the records, what I need is and average of the difference between the times. So I thought I would break this down into smaller parts.

Comment: Did you try my answer? It calculates `(MaxTime-MinTime)/(Count-1)` which is essentially the same with what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Im sorry if i am being a bit too wordy, but i cant quite glean your level of mysql experience.

Also apologies if i dont understand your question. But here goes...

First of all, you dont need to sum and devide, MySQL has an average function for you called avg(). See here for details
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

What you want can be done by sub-queries i think. For more info on subqueries look here.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Basically, you want to first create a table that sorts the column.

```
 SELECT someid, time
    FROM table
    ORDER BY TIME
```

Use that in a subquery that joins the table with itself but with a shifted index (To get the time before and time after)

```
SELECT *
    FROM table1 as t1 INNER JOIN table2 as t2 ON t1.someid = t2.someid+1
```

And use avg on that

```
SELECT avg(t2.time-t1.time)
GROUP BY t1.someid
```

Comment: Thanks @Martin Nielsenfor your response, to answer your question on how much I know about Mysql is little and working with your subquerys is pushing my knowledge to the max. Can you show me how you would assemble this as a hole query?